# Can we have Cascading and Megamenu both in SharePoint Hub site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, navigation, global-navigation, hub-site

I have SharePoint Online hub site. In hub site, we have two navigations.

1. Hub navigation
2. Site navigation

[image]

Now the requirement is: We need Mega menu navigation type in Hub Navigation and Cascading dropdown navigation type in site navigation.

Is it possible to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in SharePoint online hub sites.

> Navigation layout for hub navigation leverages the same setting as the site navigation.

**Documentation**: [Customize the navigation on your SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca)

---

**Note**: You can achieve your requirements for Hub **associated sites** using below settings:

1. Set **Mega menu** layout in main hub site: Settings > Change the look > Navigation
2. Set **Cascading** layout in associated SharePoint sites: Settings > Change the look > Navigation

**Related read**:

1. [New Navigation features for SharePoint team sites](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/09/17/new-navigation-features-for-sharepoint-team-sites/)